# Why does DateTime.ParseExact throw an exception with "dd.Mm.yyy" format and a date with a 4-digit year?

Tags: c#, datetime, string-formatting

[The documentation on yyy format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#yyySpecifier) says that it's 3 digits **or more**. So why does the following code throw an exception?

```
string format = "dd.MM.yyy";
string s = DateTime.Now.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(s, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //this throws FormatException
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iYF1bo)

Comment: `The "yyy" custom format specifier represents the year with a minimum of three digits. If the year has more than three significant digits, they are included in the result string. If the year has fewer than three digits, the number is padded with leading zeros to produce three digits.` - From the documentation you linked. The output string has 4 chars for the year, not 3. It's throwing at the end because you are saying it only has 3.

Comment: Quite a bit of the documentation does seem to be written with `ToString()`-colored spectacles. There are a few places which suggest that the `Parse` family of methods are stricter.

Comment: You should expect ParseExact to be VERY EXACT

Comment: @derekmckinnon `If the year has more than three significant digits, they are included in the result string` - I read this as "a year with more than 3 digits also complies with the format".

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug to me. I tried this to rule out any locale problems and also got the same error:

```
 string format = "dd.MM.yyy";
 string s = DateTime.Now.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(s, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //this throws FormatException
```

Edit: Looks to be a duplicate of this question: [Why can't DateTime.ParseExact parse DateTime output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321432/why-cant-datetime-parseexact-parse-datetime-output?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I tried debugging your code [image]

The string stores all 4 digits but your format asks for 3 digits in year. I guess that is why DateTime is not able to parse you string

**Try using yyyy when parsing it will solve your issue**